# What's the connection between FineUI and Newtonsoft.Json.dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

today I downloaded FineUI and wanted to try it out, but foud out it depends on Newtonsoft.Json.dll. Why is that?

Comment: Because `FineUI` use `Newtonsoft.Json` in it, you should download it also and reference both of them in your project.

Comment: @Aria The rose is red. The violet's blue. Pinocchio is smart. And so are you.

Comment: @M.R.Safari Thank you.

Comment: Why do you care why it depends on another assembly? That is the inner details of the assembly and the whole point of using an assembly is that you do not care about its implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However your question is not really a question because of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , but I am going to clear you when you want to use a library you should understand about it's dependencies which specify library use that dependecies to be work, so the [NewtonSoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) is a library to manipulate JSON data in .Net (Serializing,Deserializing) which means `FineUI` use that to work with JSON data easy.

For example in [ControlBase.cs](https://github.com/corew/FineUI/blob/master/FineUI/BaseWebControls/ControlBase/ControlBase.cs) of `FineUI` the `NewtonSoft` used directly:

```
internal object GetPropertyJSONValue(string prop)
{
    object propValue = null;

    PropertyInfo info = this.GetType().GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (info != null)
    {
        propValue = info.GetValue(this, null);

        if (info.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
        {
            propValue = StringUtil.EnumToName((Enum)propValue);
        }
        else if (info.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Array))
        {
            if (propValue == null)
            {
                propValue = new JArray();
            }
            else
            {
                propValue = new JArray((Array)propValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return propValue;
}
```

`JArray` is a class of `NewtonSoft` which means `FineUI` need `NewtonSoft` to be work.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!